# Model falls through heightmap terrain

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm using gazebo 1.5 on gentoo linux.  I installed it from dev branch about a month ago.

When I create a terrain using a heightmap and try to insert a model onto it, the model falls through the terrain and out of sight.  I've tried it with the pioneer robots and with various other models - same result.  However, with the Brickbox, Bookshelf, and Cabinet, they stay where I put them.  I don't know how to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1980/model-falls-through-heightmap-terrain/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-20**:
Can you please post your SDF?

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-21**:
http://pastebin.com/htw8NR56

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-25**:
any clues?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-26**:
It looks like you scaled the heightmap in the visual but not in the geometry.

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-28**:
It worked!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Question answered in comments.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1